# SSRS expression on report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I have this expression  in report but not display when I ran the report, no error. Can you help please.

```
=iif(Parameters!daterange.Value = 10000, "As of: " & First(Fields!mindate.Value, "TopExecutedReports"), "")
```

It's correct. Mistaken

Comment: what is data type of  `Parameters!daterange.Value` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just assuming that in Report `Dataset` you have set `Daterange` datatype as a `VARCHAR()` *(It can be because of your requirement)*

So you should try something like below,

**`=IIF(Parameters!daterange.Value = "10000", "As of: " + First(Fields!mindate.Value, "TopExecutedReports"), "")`**